# How to emit Flow value from different function? Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a flow :

```kotlin
val myflow = kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow<Message>{}
```

and want to emit values with function:

```kotlin
override suspend fun sendMessage(chat: Chat, message: Message) {
    myflow.emit(message)
}
```

But compiler does not allow me to do this, is there any workarounds to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot access externally declared and instantiated variable? You pass flow's reference to the function or, much better, encapsulate the reference to the flow in your class throw constructor/builder as a required parameter. Can you share an error with us?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The answer of Animesh Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61655623/10971172) is pretty much correct. You can also return a [Channel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) as a flow (see [consumeAsFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/consume-as-flow.html) or [asFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/as-flow.html) on a [BroadcastChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-broadcast-channel/index.html)).

But there is also a thing called [`StateFlow`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1973) currently in development by Kotlin team, which is, in part, meant to implement a similar behavior, although it is unknown when it is going to be ready.

EDIT: [`StateFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) and [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) have been released as part of a stable API (https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/10/kotlinx-coroutines-1-4-0-introducing-stateflow-and-sharedflow/). These tools can and should be used when state management is required in an async execution context.

Comment: Correct +1 for that, they are capable of becoming flow, but note that they will still going to be hot.

Comment: It seems just a few hours ago the [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/index.html) was introduced in a [coroutines release 1.3.6](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/1.3.6)

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64148101/1015126 there are limitations based on collection speed caused by StateFlow being conflated. Be careful!

Answer (score 17):

You can use ***StateFlow*** or ***SharedFlow*** APIs for such use case.
Here's a sample code with the usage of ***StateFlow***.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

val chatFlow = MutableStateFlow<String>("")
    
fun main() = runBlocking {

    // Observe values
    val job = launch {
        chatFlow.collect {
            print("$it ")
        }
    }

    // Change values
    arrayOf("Hey", "Hi", "Hello").forEach {
        delay(100)
        sendMessage(it)
    }

    delay(1000)
    
    // Cancel running job
    job.cancel()
    job.join()
}

suspend fun sendMessage(message: String) {
    chatFlow.value = message
}
```

You can test this code by running below snippet.

```html
<iframe src="https://pl.kotl.in/DUBDfUnX3" style="width:600px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Flow is self contained, once the block (lambda) inside the flow is executed the flow is over, you've to do operations inside and emit them from there.

Here is the similar [github issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1448), says:

> Afaik Flow is designed to be a self contained, replayable, cold stream, so emission from outside of it's own scope wouldn't be part of the contract. I think what you're looking for is a Channel.

And IMHO you're probably looking at the [Channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html#channel-basics), or specifically a [ConflatedBroadcastChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/) for multiple receivers. The difference between a normal channel and a broadcast channel is that multiple receivers can listen to a broadcast channel using [openSubscription](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/open-subscription.html) function which returns a ReceiveChannel associated with the BroadcastChannel.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `SharedStateFlow` it has got everything you need.

**Initialization of your flow:**

```kotlin
val myFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Message>()
```

and now it should just work as you were trying earlier with:

```kotlin
override suspend fun sendMessage(chat: Chat, message: Message) {
    myFlow.emit(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a channel like:

```
 private val _navigationAction = Channel<Route>(Channel.CONFLATED)
override val navigationAction : Flow<Route> = _navigationAction.receiveAsFlow()


override fun navigateTo(target: Route) {
    _navigationAction.trySend(target)
}
```