# kotlin flow is not emitting values from different function

Tags: kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to implement kotlin stateflow, but not able to know the reason why it is not working.

Current output:
 verificatio 34567

Expected Output:
 verificatio 34567
 verificatio failed

```
package stateflowDuplicate

import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() = runBlocking {
val firebasePhoneVerificationListener = FirebaseOTPVerificationOperation1()
val oTPVerificationViewModal = OTPVerificationViewModal1(firebasePhoneVerificationListener)
oTPVerificationViewModal.fail()
}

class OTPVerificationViewModal1(private val firebasePhoneVerificationListener: FirebaseOTPVerificationOperation1) {

init {
    startPhoneNumberVerification()
    setUpListener()
}

 suspend fun fail(){
    firebasePhoneVerificationListener.fail()
}

private fun startPhoneNumberVerification() {
    firebasePhoneVerificationListener.initiatePhoneVerification("34567")
}

private fun setUpListener() {
    runBlocking {
        firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneVerificationFailed.collect {
            println("verificatio $it")
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
Second class
package stateflowDuplicate

import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class FirebaseOTPVerificationOperation1 {

private val _phoneVerificationFailed = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
val phoneVerificationFailed: StateFlow<String?>
    get() = _phoneVerificationFailed

  fun initiatePhoneVerification(phoneNumber: String) {
         _phoneVerificationFailed.value = phoneNumber
}
 suspend fun fail() {
     delay(200L)
    _phoneVerificationFailed.value = "failed"
}
```

}

Tried to understand the concept from these links,
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655136/how-to-emit-flow-value-from-different-function-kotlin-coroutines)
[Link2](https://medium.com/scalereal/stateflow-end-of-livedata-a473094229b3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start a new coroutine to call `collect` because the coroutine will keep collecting values until its Job gets cancelled. Don't use `runBlocking` builder for that, use `launch` builder instead:

```
private fun setUpListener() = launch {
    firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneVerificationFailed.collect {
        println("verificatio $it")
    }
}
```

Now to make it work you need to implement `CoroutineScope` interface in your class. You can do it like this:

```
class OTPVerificationViewModal1(
    private val firebasePhoneVerificationListener: FirebaseOTPVerificationOperation1
): CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {
    ...
}
```

If you run it now you will get this output:

```
verificatio 34567
verificatio failed
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but can u please tell me why it was not working with viewmodal as coroutinescope is by default exist in that with ktx

Comment: Please look into this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331931/mutablestateflow-is-not-emitting-values-after-1st-time-kotlin-coroutine , the issue is same but it is with viewmodal android

Comment: please help me with above linked question, as i have done everything as per current answer here, but still not firing

Comment: @Reprator I saw your code but it's hard to keep track since there are parts that are not clear what they do. I would use the Log to see if every method is being called. For example inside `secondCall` method, inside `resendPhoneVerificationCode` method, etc.

Comment: please go through the question once again, i have updated the question with minimal code, and current and expected output

Comment: Is this done in a ViewModel?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky ViewModels have their own coroutine scope (`viewModelScope`). Use that one if you need to launch coroutines.