# MutableStateFlow is not emitting values after 1st emit kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

This is my FirebaseOTPVerificationOperation class, where my MutableStateFlow properties are defined, and values are changed,

```
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class FirebaseOTPVerificationOperation @Inject constructor(
    private val activity: Activity,
    val logger: Logger
) {
    private val _phoneAuthComplete = MutableStateFlow<PhoneAuthCredential?>(null)
    val phoneAuthComplete: StateFlow<PhoneAuthCredential?>
        get() = _phoneAuthComplete

    private val _phoneVerificationFailed = MutableStateFlow<String>("")
    val phoneVerificationFailed: StateFlow<String>
        get() = _phoneVerificationFailed

    private val _phoneCodeSent = MutableStateFlow<Boolean?>(null)
    val phoneCodeSent: StateFlow<Boolean?>
        get() = _phoneCodeSent

    private val _phoneVerificationSuccess = MutableStateFlow<Boolean?>(null)
    val phoneVerificationSuccess: StateFlow<Boolean?>
        get() = _phoneVerificationSuccess

    fun resendPhoneVerificationCode(phoneNumber: String) {
        _phoneVerificationFailed.value = "ERROR_RESEND"
    }
}
```

This is my viewmodal, from where i am listening the changes in stateflow properties, as follows,

```
class OTPVerificationViewModal @AssistedInject constructor(
    private val coroutinesDispatcherProvider: AppCoroutineDispatchers,
    private val firebasePhoneVerificationListener: FirebaseOTPVerificationOperation,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    @AssistedInject.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): OTPVerificationViewModal
    }

    val phoneAuthComplete = viewModelScope.launch {
        firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneAuthComplete.filter {
            Log.e("1","filter auth $it")
            it.isNotNull()
        }.collect {
            Log.e("2","complete auth $it")
        }
    }

    val phoneVerificationFailed = viewModelScope.launch {
        firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneVerificationFailed.filter {
            Log.e("3","filter failed $it")
            it.isNotEmpty()
        }.collect {
            Log.e("4","collect failed $it")
        }
    }

    val phoneCodeSent = viewModelScope.launch {
        firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneCodeSent.filter {
            Log.e("5","filter code $it")
            it.isNotNull()
        }.collect {
            Log.e("6","collect code $it")
        }
    }

    val phoneVerificationSuccess = viewModelScope.launch {
        firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneVerificationSuccess.filter {
            Log.e("7","filter success $it")
            it.isNotNull()
        }.collect {
            Log.e("8","collect success $it")
        }
    }

    init {
        resendVerificationCode()
        secondCall()
    }

    private fun secondCall() {
        viewModelScope.launch(coroutinesDispatcherProvider.io) {
            delay(10000)
            resendVerificationCode()
        }
    }

    fun resendVerificationCode() {
        viewModelScope.launch(coroutinesDispatcherProvider.io) {
            firebasePhoneVerificationListener.resendPhoneVerificationCode(
                getNumber()
            )
        }
    }

    private fun getNumber() =
            "+9191111116055"
}
```

The issue is that

```
firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneVerificationFailed
```

is fired in viewmodal for first call of,

```
init {
   resendVerificationCode()
}
```

but for second call of:

```
init {
   secondCall()
}
```

`firebasePhoneVerificationListener.phoneVerificationFailed` is not fired in viewmodal, I don't know why it happened, any reason or explanation will be very appericated.

Current Output:

```
filter auth null
filter failed 
filter code null
filter success null
filter failed ERROR_RESEND
collect failed ERROR_RESEND
```

Expected Output:

```
filter auth null
filter failed 
filter code null
filter success null
filter failed ERROR_RESEND
collect failed ERROR_RESEND
filter failed ERROR_RESEND
collect failed ERROR_RESEND
```

Comment: Try updating `_phoneVerificationFailed` with a different value. When you set a `StateFlow` with a value equal to the current one, its observers won't be notified. It's like using a `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

Comment: answer found, hence closing the question

Answer (score 37):

Pankaj's answer is correct, `StateFlow` won't emit the same value twice. As the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) suggests:

> Values in state flow are conflated using `Any.equals` comparison in a similar way to `distinctUntilChanged` operator. It is used to conflate incoming updates to `value` in `MutableStateFlow` and to suppress emission of the values to collectors when new value is equal to the previously emitted one.

Therefore, to resolve this issue you can create a wrapping class and override the `equals` (and `hashCode`) method to return `false` even if the classes are in fact the same:

```kotlin
sealed class VerificationError {
    object Resend: VerificationError()

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return Random.nextInt()
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue per se, but it helped me troubleshoot whether or not the state change was being seen by the flow - it was not

Answer (score 30):

StateFlow is SharedFlow:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034

---

Described in more detail in my article: https://veldan1202.medium.com/kotlin-setup-sharedflow-31debf613b91

---

```
val shared = MutableSharedFlow(
    replay = 1,
    onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST,
)
shared.tryEmit(value)
```

Comment: Yes, but it is more convenient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5279156/vlad - SharedFlow instead of StateFlow is necessary when you can emit the same values in a row, since StateFlow does not collect duplicate elements.

Comment: What is the point of this answer?  What is it explaning.

Comment: The downside of using `MutableSharedFlow` is that emitting is a suspending function and thus has to be called in a coroutine scope. `tryEmit` can result in a failure based on buffer, you should add that note into your answer.

Comment: Using emit only should work too.

Answer (score 13):

The value emitted by state flow is conflated and doesn't emit the same consecutive result twice, you can think as if a condition check is validating the old emitted value is not equal to the newly emitted value.

Current Output:
filter auth null
filter failed
filter code null
filter success null
filter failed ERROR_RESEND
collect failed ERROR_RESEND

(filter failed ERROR_RESEND
collect failed ERROR_RESEND) This being the same old value which was emitted so you will not see them getting emitted.

Answer (score 12):

Use a `Channel`: this does emit after sending the same value twice.

1. Add this to your ViewModel

   `val _intent = Channel<Intent>(Channel.CONFLATED)`
2. Put values using `send` / `trySend`

   `_intent.send(intentLocal)`
3. observe as flow

   `_intent.consumeAsFlow().collect { //do something }`

Comment: `Channel` is better than `MutableStateFlow`?

Comment: `MutableStateFlow` is conflated by nature, so you should use `Channel.CONFLATED` to mimic it's behavior

Comment: channels are deprecated. use SharedFlow, not StateFlow

Comment: @deviant What if you want to keep the .value ?

Comment: @deviant Channel is not deprecated, where did you get that?

Answer (score 4):

I think I have some more in-depth understanding of this issue. The first thing to be sure is that for StateFlow, it is not recommended to use variable collection types (such as **MutableList**, etc.). Because **MutableList** is not thread safe. If there are multiple references in the core code, it may cause the program to crash.

Before, the method I used was to wrap the class and override the equals method. However, I think this solution is not the safest method. The safest way is for deep copy, Kotlin provides `toMutableList()` and `toList()` methods are both deep copy. The **emit** method judges whether there is a change depends on whether the result of `equals()` is equal.

The reason I have this problem is that the data type using `emit()` is: `SparseArray<MutableList<String>>`. **StateFlow** calls the equals method for **SparseArray**. When `MutableList<String>` changes, the result of equals does not change at this time (even if the `equals` and `hashcode` methods of `MutableList<String>` change).

Finally, I changed the type to `SparseArray<List<String>>`. Although the performance loss caused by adding and deleting data, this also solves the problem fundamentally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, calling kotlin toList() and toMutableList() did the job. You saved My Day.

Comment: This is incorrect. toMutableList() and toList() are not deep copy APIs. If you have a list of objects and one of the objects' fields was update StateFlow will not recognize this as a change and will not emit the new value.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, LiveData emits data every time, while StateFlow emits only different values. [tryEmit()](https://blog.danlew.net/2021/03/23/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-tryemit/) doesn't work. In my case I found two solutions.

1. If you have `String` data, you can emit again this way:

   ```
   private fun emitNewValue() {
       subscriber.value += " "
       subscriber.value.dropLast(1)
   }
   ```

   For another class you can use this (or create an extension function):

   ```
    private fun <T> emitNewValue(value: T) {
        if (subscriber.value == value) {
            subscriber.value = null
        }
        subscriber.value = value
    }
   ```

But it's a bad and buggy way (values are emitted *twice* additionally).

2. Try to find all subscribers that change their values. It can be not evident. For instance, focus change listener, `Switch` (checkbox). When you toggle `Switch`, a text can also change, so you should subscribe to this listener. The same way when you focus other view, an error text can change.

Answer (score 2):

Use wrapper object with any unique id, for example:

```
class ViewModel {
    
    private val _listFlow = MutableStateFlow(ListData(emptyList()))
    val listFlow: StateFlow<ListData> get() = _listFlow

    fun update(list:List<String>){
        _listFlow.value = ListData(list)    
    }

    data class ListData constructor(
        val list: List<String>,
        private val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),//added unique id
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to emit same value more than once than use MutableSharedFlow instead of MutableStateFlow.

Like this

```
private val _categoriesFlow: MutableSharedFlow<List<Category>> = MutableSharedFlow()
val categoriesFlow: MutableSharedFlow<List<Category>> = _categoriesFlow
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after merging the streams.
The emit() function will not be executed if == is used to determine equality.

The way to solve the problem: You can wrap a layer and rewrite the hashCode() and equals() methods. The equals() method directly returns false.
This solution works in my code. The stream after the combine has also changed.

Pankaj's answer is correct, StateFlow will not emit the same value twice.

Before wrapping, the result of == is still true even if the content is different.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was hashCode() and equals() . After adding new field, didn't update them.

Answer (score -1):

You could make _phoneVerificationFailed nullable and send null between the two calls!

Comment: that just kills the purpose of ? nullablilty feature of kotlin